# Where is the source code of UbuntuTouch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I want to change the UbuntuTouch in Nexus 5 (it is a mobile phone) at the system level.
How I can do that?
Is there any site for the source code?
Is there any software development environment? because I have to cross compile the code from x86_64 (under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) to the SOC of Nexus 5
appreciating for the replies in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the Ubuntu Touch source code links on the wiki here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Contribute#Source_code

It also has information about how to patch and submit your own contributions.

App development is done using [Bazaar](https://help.launchpad.net/Code) and merged back to the individual launchpad projects.

Android development is essentially a clone of Cyanogen Mod.